# How do you download a website?

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

Search engine bots crawl the web and download each page they go to for analysis, right?

How exactly do they download a page? What way do they store the pages?

I am asking because I want to run an analysis on a few webpages. I could scrape the page by going to the address but wouldn't it make more sense to download the pages to my computer and work on them from there?

Comment: It's useful to become familiar with how web pages actually work.  Your browser views a webpage by sending an HTTP request to a server, which responds by sending the HTML for the website back to your computer.  Any programming language that can send HTTP requests can be used to receive HTML data.

Comment: As a general problem, this is not trivial.  A real web crawler has to parse dynamic pages and script, in many cases rendering the complete page before the links become retrievable.  There may be permanent or temporary redirects, unique links based on session ID, CSS, etc., etc.  The appropriate tool depends on the nature and complexity of the pages involved.  If you just want to mirror flat pages, see the suggestions below.  Want more than that?  Depends on the pages in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wget --mirror`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I am looking for. From looking it up, it seems Python has it's own versions.

Answer (score 7):

Try [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

About the way they do it:
The indexing starts from a designated starting point (an entrance if you prefer). From there, the spider follows recursively all hyperlinks until a given depth.

Search engine spiders work like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/Web_Crawler.aspx) as well, but there are many crawling simultaneously and there are other factors that count. For example a newly created post here in SO will be picked up by google very fast, but an update at a low traffic web site will be picked up even days later.

Comment: How does Google pick up changes in dynamic pages so fast? Keeping an eye on a sites RSS feed seems like a good idea. How do RSS readers pick up on changes of an RSS feed instantly?

Comment: @GreenRails, dynamic sites publish their changes with PubSubHubbub, and Google subscribes to that.  For instance, my Wordpress blog uses PubSubHubbub, and changes appear on Google Reader and other RSS feeds faster than I can refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the debugging tools built into Firefox (or firebug) and Chrome to examine how the page works. As far as downloading them directly, I am not sure. You could maybe try viewing the page source in your browser, and then copy and paste the code.